# objective c Accessing deallocated object

Tags: objective-c, nullpointerexception, crash, exc-bad-access

What will happen if below codes execute?

```
NSData* data =  [myArray objectAtIndex:i] // assigning from array
[myArray removeAllObjects]; // removing all objects from array.
[self doSomething:data]; // this method will execute some operations with data
```

Is data turned into a zombie object which might cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wouldn't cause a crash. Your `data` is just a pointer, holding the same numerical (virtual) memory address where the NSData data is stored. If one of the pointers is set to point to nil, or to some other data for that matter, it won't trigger any change in the NSData nor the other pointer.

Comment: You are right. I thought, removing all objects from a mutable array will deallocate all the allocated memory but it just decrease a retain count for each object of the array.
Thanks